# Python Converting a List into an Array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabula-py

I have a list that is 5 rows by 5 columns.

I am trying to convert this list into a dataframe.

When I try to do so, it only grabs the first row.

This failed because I had it set to 5,5:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(pdf_read).reshape(5,5),columns=list("abcde"))
```

When I switched it to this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(pdf_read).reshape(1,5),columns=list("abcde"))
```

It only grabbed the first row.

1. Why does it do this?
2. Any advice?

Edit: Added Context

I am using the `tabula` module in python to read a PDF file.
The PDF file results are stored in the variable `pdf_read`.

When I do `len(pdf_read)` it has a length of 1, but when I type
`print(pdf_read)` it says it is 5 rows x 5 columns, which is very strange.

Edit #2:  Datatypes

I ran the following:

```
print(type(pdf_read))
print(type(pdf_read[0]))
```

I got `<class 'list'>` and `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` respectively.

It seems I have a Dataframe inside of a list.

I ran this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    pdf_read[0],columns=["column_a","column_b","column_c","column_d","column_e"]
    )
```

This just returns a 5,5 dataframe, but all of the values in each column are NaN.

Some progress made, but will need to figure out why the values are not populated now.

Comment: kindly share your list, with the expected output

Comment: Added some more context, the data is sensitive so I'm trying to avoid posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After some [research](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/examples/tabula_example.ipynb) output `pdf_read` is list of DataFrames.

So for first `DataFrame`:

```
df = pdf_read[0]
```

Comment: Added some more context, I'm trying to avoid posting the actual data because it's sensitive.

Comment: @LunchBox what is `print (np.array(pdf_read).shape)` ?

Comment: (1,5) is what gets returned

Comment: @LunchBox - And what is if use `print (type(pdf_read))` and `print (type(pdf_read[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'list'> and
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> respectively